# How add to clipboard image in browser on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, web, blob, clipboard

I'd like to add some image to `clipboard` from my web browser(Chrome, Safari) on iPhone. On the MacBook, Windows laptops, Android devices, in chrome all correct work, but on iPhones nope ((

1. I have canvas element with some picture.
2. I get from the canvas element Blob type of data
3. Create "ClipboardItem" with correct type and data
4. Add to ClipboardItem to clipboard using write
5. And on the MacBook, Windows laptops, Android devices, in chrome all correct work, but on iPhones nope ((

Help me please, my code example here

`
canvasEl.toBlob((blob) => {
if (!blob) return;

```
    navigator.clipboard.write([
        new ClipboardItem({
            "image/png": new Promise(async (resolve) => {
                resolve(new Blob([blob!], { type: "image/png" }));
            }),
        }),
    ]);
});
```

`